# Error while using lookup function

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two Sheets . Sheet1 : Last week, and sheet2 : This week.

I am looking for my ID in column A of sheet2 with sheet1, and if they match, I am copying the values from column M of sheet1 to column M of sheet2.

Due to some reason, the values that i dont find in sheet1 are getting filled as "0". I dont want this to occur, with my code. I just want the code to look for ID, if they match i want the value, else i dont want anything to be printed.

Could someone suggest Where i am going wrong ?

```
Sub lookup()
Dim tr As Long
Dim trsh As Long
tr = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
trsh = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("M2:M" & tr).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("A2:A" & trsh), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 13, 0), "")
End Sub
```

[image: This is how my sheet1, resembles. I have the ID in column A and the Repsonsible in column M and the Updates in N and o respectively.]
[image: So, this is my sheet2, this week. Assuming the ID in column A and Result in column M. I have highlighted my result in red,( Even i dont find the ID, i get them printed as 0), I dont Need this. I have in the next column, the result i am expecting]

Comment: `tr` and `trsh` are both referring to `Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Ya, its wrong ?

Comment: @Mrig  How can I get rid of that ?

Comment: Could you post sample data so that people here can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mrig  I tried to use just tr and i get the 0 in that case as well,, I also tried to do it with Tr as Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  and trsh as Sheets("LastWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Still i get the error

Comment: @Mrig will a snapshot work ?

Comment: Will do, include the issue scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("M2:M" & tr).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("A2:A" & trsh), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 13, 0), "")
```

try

```
Dim cel as Range
For Each cel In Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("M2:M" & tr)
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel, Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 13, 0), "")
Next cel
```

Though your code can be modified using worksheet and range variable. And make sure you use correct `tr` and `trsh`.

**EDIT:**

---

```
Sub lookupPSQM()
    Dim thisWeekLR As Long, lastWeekLR As Long
    Dim thisWeekSht As Worksheet, lastWeekSht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    Set thisWeekSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ThisWeek")
    Set lastWeekSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LastWeek")

    thisWeekLR = thisWeekSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'lastWeekLR = lastWeekSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = thisWeekSht.Range("A2:A" & thisWeekLR)

    For Each cel In rng
        cel.Offset(0, 12).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel, Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 13, 0), "")
    Next cel
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

**Sheet *LastWeek***

[image]

**Sheet *ThisWeek***

[image]

Comment: The result I expected is correct, but now all my data in column N disappeared, why is that so ?

Comment: @Jenny - As per the screen shot you attached, I thought for values in `Column M` you want result in `Column N`

Comment: @Jenny - In which column you want results to be displayed?

Comment: Sorry Mrig for the confusion. I want my result in Column M

Comment: Fine, I have my data in sheet1 in column M and I want the Vlookup data to be in sheet2 of column M

Comment: the last suggested code, worked fine. This code is producing the same result as mine. With the last code, it was just an issue that, it deleted my column N

Comment: @Jenny - Updated code should work fine. I've tested it. Please confirm that you ID's in both sheet are in `Column A` and values are in `Column M` of sheet `LastWeek` and same has to be displayed in `Column M` of `ThisWeek`

Comment: My ID are in column A in both the Sheets. and the values are in column M of both the Sheets. I dont know due to some reason in my rows of 55 to 61, i get it printed as 0

Comment: @Jenny - I've added images to show this solution works fine. Is it possible for you to share your file with sample data probably leaving row 55 to 61 as it is.

Comment: I cant share the data. I will try to work on it. Thank you that you helped me so much .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149697/discussion-between-mrig-and-jenny).

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

Please correct the sheet reference if required. Currently it assumes that the sheets are called as ThisWeek and LastWeek.

```
Sub lookupPSQM()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim tr As Long

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set wsSource = Sheets("LastWeek")
Set wsDest = Sheets("ThisWeek")

tr = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wsDest.Range("M2:M" & tr).Formula = "=IfError(VLookup(A2,'" & wsSource.Name & "'!A:M, 13, 0), """")"

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No way. If the ID in column A on ThisWeek sheet isn't found in column A on LastWeek Sheet, the formula will return a null string "" in the formula cells. I tested it with some dummy data and it returns blanks in the formula cells.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR(), vDB2
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set toWs = Sheets("ThisWeek")
    Set Ws = Sheets("LastWeek")

    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vDB2 = toWs.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    n = UBound(vDB2, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 2 To n
        For j = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            If vDB2(i, 1) = vDB(j, 1) Then
                vR(i - 1, 1) = vDB(j, 13)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    toWs.Range("m2").Resize(n - 1) = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you Please comment the lines what it does. It is hard for me to understand

Comment: This code get data of sheets by array, After two array compare, if two array is same then set data to new array vR().  Finally record  the result array  to your sheet range.